# smitten with/by

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, past-participles, animacy

[Fowler's **smit** reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA755&dq=%22when%20the%20object%20of%20the%20fascination%20is%20a%20person%22&pg=PA755#v=onepage&q=%22when%20the%20object%20of%20the%20fascination%20is%20a%20person%22&f=false)

> Its
> most frequent use is as the participle **smitten**, ‘infatuated,
> fascinated’. When the object of the fascination is a person, **with** is much more
> often used than *by*; when the object is inanimate, the pattern is the
> opposite.

What are the reasons for such choice?

OED: https://oed.com/oed2/00228565  AND  https://oed.com/oed2/00228536

Comment: *Smitten* in *smitten with* functions like an adjective. *Smitten* in *smitten by* displays the passive voice.

Comment: @TinfoilHat **ENAMOR** (transitive) to fill or inflame with love (**usually used in the passive and followed by of or sometimes with**):  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/enamored

Comment: @TinfoilHat **SMITE** (transitive) **[usually: be + smitten]**
to affect mentally, morally, or emotionally with a strong and sudden feeling. https://www.wordreference.com/definition/smite

Comment: @TinfoilHat OED: https://oed.com/oed2/00228565 AND https://oed.com/oed2/00228536

Comment: _Smitten_, like most perfect participles, can refer to a past event, or to the results of that event. _By_ is the agentive marker for passive, so _smitten by X_ refers to some previous smiting that X did to the subject. If _smitten_ refers to the present resultant state rather than the past event, you'd use a different -- and arbitrarily chosen -- preposition, in this case _with_, which is determined by the participle _smitten_, rather than by the requirements of the passive construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/smitten_1?q=smitten

Comment: @GJC: What is your thesis with your various links? That *smitten* is an adjective whether followed by *with* or *by*? Or that the passive-voice agent can appear not just in a *by*-phrase but also in a *with*-phrase?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a choice, it is usage. According to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smitten%20with%20you%2C%20%20smitten%20by%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmitten%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmitten%20by%20you%3B%2Cc0), especially from the ‘80s.

This  ***[site](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/smitten)*** suggests the following nuances between “smitten with” vs “smitten by:”

> Both smitten by and smitten with appear to be acceptable. Smitten with may be slightly more common, but not by much. If you feel the need to make a distinction, being smitten by someone could imply some sort of action on the part of the adored person; being smitten with someone could imply that he or she is unaware of your affection and has done nothing to encourage it—but those aren't hard-and-fast rules.

(quickanddirtytips.com)

Comment: Sensibly balanced.

Comment: OED: https://oed.com/oed2/00228565 AND https://oed.com/oed2/00228536